# Ionic state not work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have problem with state (I don't understand how it works).

Ok my app.js code view this:

```
....
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
// $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
 $stateProvider
           .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/home.html',
            controller: 'AppController',
            abstract: true
          })
           .state('app.aquarium', {
            url: '/aquarium/index',
            views: {
              'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'tpl/aquarium/index.html',
                controller: 'AquariumIndexCtrl',
              }
            }
          })
....
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/aquarium/index');

....

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    console.log("App");
});
app.controller('AquariumIndexCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log("Akwaria");
});
....
```

and in index.html I have href to this states:

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#/app/aquarium/index">
    <i class="icon"><img src="img/aquarium.png" /></i>
    Aq
  </a>
```

But All the time I see the file from state "app" (tpl/home.html).

Why my link dont works and Why still load file tpl/home.html when on start app I use "redirect" to

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/aquarium/index');
```

? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to pass the dependencies as an array of strings when you inyect them. If not, by the time you uglify to production you will have problems with them.

```
app.config([
  $stateProvider, 
  $urlRouterProvider, 
  $ionicConfigProvider,  
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
}])
```

Around the state problem:

The state depends directly to the ui-views you have stablished before, in this case i think you want to set them in your index.
Think about the ui-views as boxes you will fill with html calling them from the states or url depending you structure your app by states or urls.

Using states:

Assuming your index.html, you need to create the ui-views to fill with the html from the states.

```
<div ui-view="menuContent">

</div>
```

I don't know if you are declaring the ui-view, i suppose yes. 
In the abstract state you should call as well to the ui-view using views and filling it with content that won't needed to be called again later, if not at least declare it empty.

```
app.config([
  $stateProvider, 
  $urlRouterProvider, 
  $ionicConfigProvider,  
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

// $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
 $stateProvider
           .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            views: {
             'menuContent': {}
            },
            abstract: true
          })
           .state('app.aquarium', {
            url: '/aquarium/index',
            views: {
              'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'tpl/aquarium/index.html',
                controller: 'AquariumIndexCtrl',
              }
            }
          })
....
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/aquarium/index');

}])
```

Think about ui-view menuContent as a box that will be filled dinamically depending of the state you call, you can have as many ui-views as you want and load them one by one only if you set them in the views: {} state.

finally you should be using ui-sref instead of href to call the diferent states:

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.aquarium">
   <i class="icon"><img src="img/aquarium.png" /></i>
</a>
```